# Insert counter variable inside body data of http sampler in jmeter

Tags: json, http, jmeter, counter, performance-testing

I am using jmeter to simulate concurrent users when doing a transaction. I have a field named "TransactionReference" which is unique. What I want to do is to be able to make these users transact.

What I did so far was I recorded the transaction process (using HTTP Test Script Recorder) and I got a static value for the TransactionReference. So everytime I run my test script, it does not insert the new transaction created because the TransactionReference is not unique anymore. I tried to make it dynamic (auto incremental) by using the Counter Config element. I have a variable named "ctr" and I call it in the body data using "${ctr}". However, I am getting a "MalformedJsonException" in my logs.

My question is, how am I supposed to call my counter variable inside my http sampler post body data correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to one of the following reasons:

- your Counter element configuration is incorrect
- you don't need quotation marks around the variable reference
- JSON is broken for any other reason

So the following workarounds are available:

1. Double check your Counter configuration
2. Use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener to see what is actually being sent
3. Use [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function in the "global" mode instead of `${ctr}` variable like:

   ```
   ${__counter(FALSE,)}
   ```

More information: [How to Use a Counter in a JMeter Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-counter-jmeter-test)